# How to move review tab in product page

Tags: customer, magento-1, product-view, tabs

I use `porto` theme and add attribute tab on product page . Now, I wanted to ask
how to move review tab ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check in theme layout files have below code

```
<reference name="product.info">
     <block type="review/product_view_list" name="product.reviews" as="reviews" template="review/product/view/list.phtml" after="additional">
         <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
         <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Reviews</value></action>
      </block>
 </reference>
```

You can move the tab by changing this code **after="additional"** .
Change tab name instead of additional.

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite the `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Tabs` block and add some sorting or add sorting in the `app/design/frontend/smartwave/porto/template/catalog/product/view/tabs.phtml` 
Sample (for template):

```
$tabs = $this->getTabs();
$newTabs = array();
$searchableTabs = array();
$otherTabs = array();
foreach ($tabs as $tab) {
    if ($tab['alias'] == 'review_tabbed') {
        $searchableTabs[0] = $tab;
    } else {
        $otherTabs[] = $tab;
    }
}
$newTabs = array_merge($searchableTabs, $otherTabs);
```

and change (at line ~8)

```
foreach ($this->getTabs() as $_index => $_tab):
```

to

```
foreach ($newTabs as $_index => $_tab):
```

Comment: i got move review tab to last tab .

Comment: Just change $searchableTabs[0] to $searchableTabs[99]

Comment: thanks but i not find $searchableTabs[0] in magento file ! Where do I find ?

Comment: If you want use my sample, you could add that code to the template by yourself https://gyazo.com/a7e5e749021c881b1463df062102f82c